# Can I obtain my bitcoin wallet files back from my HDD from the old OS?

Tags: wallet, wallet-recovery, wallet.dat

So i guess now its good time again to give my lost wallet files another attempt.

I'm an idiot for doing such a thing but then I heard perhaps I can unformat my HDD and retrieve my files back.

I definitely have an idea of the passwords I used and that won't be the issue.

I was buying btc around 2014-2015. I then decided to install a new mobo and I believe I wasn't able to unless I reinstalled Windows. I used the windows usb to re-install everything but I'm not sure. It was a very long time ago.

I also don't know if it was Bitcoin Core or MultiBit app that I was using on the desktop. Either way, I believe the files should be in the same place i.e. APP DATA > ROAMING > etc etc.

Is it possible to use a program like EaseUs to recover these files?

Is anybody willing to help me figure out if the files are completely gone forever or its still hidden under the old partition (which hopefully isn't over written).

Would it be perhaps under the Window.old folder? (i'm not sure if I have that folder, I need to double check back at work).

I was using WINDOWS 10 and nothing else I think.

If anyone can help me retrieve, I will personally send 0.3 BTC to you from that wallet. :)

Thanks for reading guys.

Hope you can help.

Louis

Comment: After you format your windows, did you put many other data in it?

Comment: Hi. I think I just reinstalled most of the programs but I do not think I intentionally over written data in those specific folders. Since it was a new OS install, I'm guessing the old files won't show up and will either be in 'Windows.old' folder perhaps. If not, then only an un-formatting software may be the last option?

Comment: But I guess after you format the PC you used it, I am just trying to know if you used it a lot or you are still using it because when you format your PC and you start to use the new fresh system, the system will overwrite the old files as much as you use it. If you didn't use it so much, maybe it is possible to recover some files that have not been overwritten.

Comment: Hi. Yes I just continued usage like normal but not heavily. I do not download many things so continued usage is more like playing games or using the browsers. I guess there is still hope. What steps would you take to figure out if my files are still somewhat available somewhere in the app data folder?

Comment: Hello! I would try a recover data software like this one: https://www.cleverfiles.com/disk-drill-win.html. The entire scan of your HD it should take several hours, after that you will have many data, you can try to search for the files with .dat extension, then you take a look if there is something similiar to your wallet.dat file. You can direct me on telegram, it is a fast way @lucablight

Comment: The files I would be looking for are from 2015 and sadly there is no record of them :( Thanks for your help anyway